# “I hope for it to have helped you”?

Tags: subjunctives

I see they use “I hope (that) it has helped you”, but I can’t understand the use of the indicative mood above the subjunctive mood there. Any explanation whatsoever? Can I use the structure stated in/on the title freely?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: We can use "I hope [that]" before any positive statement - "You are feeling better"; "You don't mind me asking"; "You [will] have a good holiday". The structure in the title is not idiomatic English.

Comment: Please explain why you think that the subjunctive mood is used there. (Or did you mean "instead of" instead of "above"?)

Comment: @KateBunting Why with positive statements the indicative mood?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan the complementiser “for” introduces clauses in subjunctive mood, whereas the complementiser “that” introduces clauses in indicative mood.

Comment: @KateBunting Consider “What I would love is for you to come”, which is a positive statement introduced by the irrealis complementiser “for”.

Comment: @LeyDidi *the complementiser “for” introduces clauses in subjunctive mood* I've seen several definitions of "subjunctive" but don't recall having seen that one. Where does it come from (a book, a website, etc.)?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes, in Radford’s book “Analising English Sentences”.